Invoking Google Cloud Run Function with oauth bearer token
I'm looking to learn how to invoke the http endpoint of a Cloud Run Function via an oauth authentication token obtained in python or in any other programming language based on a user's Google identity.
I have deployed a Google Cloud Run Function, which can be successfully invoked by its HTTP endpoint when using the gcloud provided identity:
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"

It does look like Google Cloud Run Functions may support http endpoints being invoked using oauth as:
In Google Cloud Console --> APIs & Services --> Enabled APIs & Services, I select Cloud Functions API, and select the tab "Credentials".
The tab says: Credentials compatible with this API, under which title it lists my OAuth 2.0 Client ID defined for the same Google Cloud Project which I have this API enabled for, and some service accounts which are global to the entire cloud project.
However, I could not find a way to call my Cloud Run Function's http endpoint with my signed-in google identity by passing its oauth obtained token as the oauth bearer:

    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        oauth_authorization_request_definition_file, ['openid'])
    authorization_credentials = flow.run_local_server()

    auth_token = credentials.id_token

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {auth_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers)

I get a 401 http code with:

Your client does not have permission to the requested URL

I'd really like to be able to accomplish that, since it avoids the need to place a service account key on user's machines.
I have also used gcloud CLI to the user the role roles/run.invoker, which some documentation and a banner mention should be granted ― admittedly the documentation and console UI are currently a bit confusing on that when it comes to an owner role.
Narrowing it down
Notably, the audience element included in the gcloud CLI obtained token, is not the same as the audience element included in the token obtained by my python code.
As an experiment, when I try using the token_audience argument of flow.run_local_server(), it doesn't work if I merely plug in the audience value obtained from gcloud ― I get in that case ―

oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.CustomOAuth2Error: (invalid_audience) The audience client and the client need to be in the same project.

― even though the project ID seen via $ gcloud config list and the on in my python code's oauth client definition, are the same.

P.S. As I understand it from a Google Cloud Console banner, Google Cloud Run Functions is in the process of further or re-integration into Google Cloud Run, after being rebranded from being formerly Google Cloud Functions, so there's a lot of documentation out there.

If the end user is using ADC you can get the credentials using this code (taken from official GCP page)
import urllib

import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token


def make_authorized_get_request(endpoint, audience):
    """
    make_authorized_get_request makes a GET request to the specified HTTP endpoint
    by authenticating with the ID token obtained from the google-auth client library
    using the specified audience value.
    """

    # Cloud Functions uses your function's URL as the `audience` value
    # audience = https://project-region-projectid.cloudfunctions.net/myFunction
    # For Cloud Functions, `endpoint` and `audience` should be equal

    req = urllib.request.Request(endpoint)

    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, audience)

    req.add_header("Authorization", f"Bearer {id_token}")
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    return response.read()

This code getsthe ADC that was generated when you ran gcloud auth application-default login.

Thank you, but the user of the local application isn't expected to install or use gcloud CLI. Does this really enable the users locally running the application to authenticate without a gcloud CLI flow of authentication on their part ― which flow.run_local_server() in my original code manages for them ― and then be approved under that authenticated identity to Google Cloud Run? My application is not a toolchain application extending gcloud CLI, so having users install or depend on gcloud CLI is not an option. They may rarely even use gcloud CLI for other projects with a different identity.
